# Can I map ISO standards to DOIs?

Tags: doi

DOIs are specified in ISO 26324, but can I refer to that standard by DOI? In other words, is there a systematic mapping from ISO standard numbers (possibly including parts and release years) to DOI names? Ideally, this would work in a similar way for different standard bodies as well.

For international standard book numbers there is such a mapping, for instance: the DOI name `10.97812345/67890` and the 13-digit ISBN `978-12345-67890` have the same referent, just different syntax.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the published version of the standard will have an ISBN and thus you could use the corresponding DOI, but I am guessing that you are asking for a more direct way.

Comment: Indeed I am, since the PDFs I get from my library do not show any ISBN.